# I'm creating a (very crude) calculator and would like to know what's wrong with this code

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error, calculator

```
# Pick the numbers you'd like to use
number1 = (input('What is the first number?\n'))
number2 = (input('What is the second number?\n'))
# Choose what to do with those numbers
Choice = input('Would you like to add, subtract, multiply or divide?\n ')
# Where the calculating happens, if it doesn't go through the error message asking you to use numbers will happen
try :
  # Converting the numbers from str into float, if this doesnt happen it means numbers were not used
  num1 = float(number1)
  num2 = float(number2)
  if Choice is add :
    answer = num1 + num2
    elif Choice is subtract : 
      answer = num1 - num2
        elif Choice is divide :
          answer = num1/num2
            elif Choice is multiply
              answer = num1 * num2
print(answer)

# The error message if the numbers you gave werent in numeric form
except :
  print('Please choose proper numbers in numeric form instead of letter/words')
```

This is the code, the issue I get is:

'File "main.py", line 13
elif Choice is subtract :
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax'

Any help would be appreciated, thanks :). (If this code just wouldn't work at all, please lmk. Im currently going through a book on how to code and thought this would be fun to try since I just learned about booleans and variables)

Comment: Alright so I fixed the issue with the elif not being lined up, but now line 19 with print(answer) apparently has an invalid syntax

Comment: anddd I fixed that but now when you get to the choice between adding, subtracting, dividing and multiplying it just goes to the error message :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean to do this:

```py
if Choice == 'add':
    answer = num1 + num2
elif Choice == 'subtract': 
    answer = num1 - num2
elif Choice == 'divide':
    answer = num1/num2
elif Choice == 'multiply':
    answer = num1 * num2
```

Be careful with indentation. If you have a single if / elseif / elseif / elseif / else chain, each condition should be at the same indent level, and each body should match its condition plus one indent (typically 4 spaces or 1 tab).

To compare a string captured from the user with `input()` to a literal string, you would do:

```py
if Choice == 'add':
```

You need to specify the quotation marks around `'add'`, otherwise it would try to reference a variable called `add`, which isn't defined.

For `==` vs `is` when checking the string, see [Why does comparing strings using either '==' or 'is' sometimes produce a different result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce-a-differe)

Comment: ohh thanks, what is "is" used for then?

Comment: @ThymeTravler I updated the answer, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce-a-differe . My understanding is that "is" checks if it is actually the same instance of the string, but "==" checks if they have the same value.